# Trying To Apply Cookies To My URL Change Button Function

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, href, attr

So I'm working on an image gallery in html using JQuery and Cookies, but I'm stuck on applying cookies to my button that changes the href onclick.

```
$(document).ready(function frank(){
$("button").click(function (){
    $("#frank1").attr("href", "link");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `jquery.cookie.min.js` and set `cookie` like below.

```
var link = 'https://www.google.com/'
$("button").click(function() {
  $("#frank1").attr("href", link);
  $.cookie("cookieName", $("#frank1").attr("href"));
  alert($.cookie("cookieName"));
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
<a id='frank1' href='#' target='_blank'>Link</a>
<button>Set Cookie</button>
```

Script is not run on snippet of Stack Overflow because:

> Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': The document is
>   sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

[But you can see; this is working on jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/d80Lv3hc/)

Comment: I ran your code on jsfiddle and it doesn't seem to be saving a cookie, it's only creating a new tab when you click on the link. Before pressing "Set Cookie" it reopens the page in a new tab and after pressing "Set Cookie" it opens google. But when you refresh the page, no cookie was saved.